# Setting priority in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

We have a table test in which we have status_cd as one of the column. Status Code can have three value - Prelim, Approved and confirmed.

I have to write a query in such a way that it should fetch the record for confirmed status cd. If confirmed status cd is not present, then fetch for Approved, if approved is not present, fetch for prelim, if prelim is also not present, fetch for null

```
id   rule_id   status_cd
1     1         prelim
2     1         null
3     1         approved
```

in above example, the query should return approved for rule_id=1

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: right now I am handling it in java code, i.e. I am fetching all the records for the rule id and storing that in the list and using predicates, I am filtering them out.

Comment: if you need the status_cd value as it is then go for another table which will have status_cd names. Here instead of that give 0-nul,1-approved-2 for prelim. then call the max with where clause for rule_id.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

```
SELECT T1.*
FROM test T1 JOIN
(SELECT *,CASE status_cd WHEN 'confirmed' THEN 1 
                         WHEN 'approved' THEN 2 
                         WHEN 'prelim' THEN 3 
                         ELSE 4 END AS Rank
 FROM test) T2 ON T1.id=T2.id AND T1.Rule_id =T2.Rule_id
ORDER BY T2.Rank
LIMIT 1
```

Result:

```
ID  RULE_ID  STATUS_CD
3   1        approved
```

Sample result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e7fb5f/10).

Answer (score 0):

Use the values '3 Confirmed','2 Approved', '1 Prelim' and '0 Null' or just use a default value of zero in a numerical field and set the value to 1, 2, 3 as the rule progresses (much faster execution, but avoid the null either way by using a default value of '0 Null' in the field if you keep a string implementation).

Then fetch the records with this query:

SELECT status_cd FROM YourTableName WHERE rule_id=1 ORDER BY status_cd DESC;

The first row of the query will always contain the answer you want. Additionally, the other rows will be there to confirm that all the other steps were present, etc. if you want to look at those rows too. If you know you only need the one row, then use

SELECT TOP 1 status_cd FROM ... (the rest is the same)